# If defined for inheriting views @BindingAdapter resolves to which one?

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

Let's assume that there is `@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")` defined for `ImageView` and `MyImageView` which inherits from `ImageView`. To which method annotated with `@BindingAdapter` would `app:imageUrl`resolve to if used in `MyImageView`?

My understanding is that due to the inheritance relationship this should be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using your `MyImageView` in your `layout.xml`, the called method will be the method declared within the `MyImageView` class. 
If this method does not exist inside this class, it will call the method of its superclass (`ImageView`) that inherits it due to inheritance. In this case the `method overload` happens.

If you are using just your `ImageView` in your `layout.xml`, the called method will be method declared inside the `ImageView` class.

Comment: This is correct. Data binding does what you intend in this case -- it chooses the most specific implementation that it can find. I haven't checked the priority of multi-attribute binding adapter, so you should verify which is chosen when you have a conflict. If I had to guess it would be that a multi attribute binding adapter takes precedence over a more specific single attribute BindingAdapter. But try it first.